# Unity, Quaternion.Euler, rotate only around Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have my main camera in the scene:

[image: My camera]

And I have this code that smoothly rotates the camera:

```
private IEnumerator SmoothlyRotateCamera()
{
    float duration = 0.3f;
    Quaternion from = transform.rotation;
    Quaternion to = from * Vector3.up * 180f;

    float elapsed = 0.0f;

    while (elapsed < duration)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(from, to, elapsed / duration);
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.rotation = to;

    isRotating = false;

    yield return null;
}
```

Currently, my camera's rotation is `[30, -60, 0]` and I want it to rotate around Y axis by 180 degrees.

In theory, to achieve that I need to rotate it for `Vector3.up * 180f`, everything sound fine, except the fact, when I rotate it that way, it also rotates all other axes as well.

If I rotate it by `new Vector3(180f, 0f, 0f)` - only X axis will be affected.

If I rotate it by `new Vector3(0f, 0f, 180f)` - only Z axis will be affected.

And if I rotate it by `new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f)` - all of the axis will rotate as well.

I've checked the rotation by setting my X rotation to 0, so now my camera's rotation is `[0, -60, 0]` and if I rotate it the way it intended to be, by `Vector3.up * 180f`, then everything works fine! BUT, I need my camera's X to stay in the place. E.g., rotation in the Editor itself only by Y gives me the result that I want.

What should I do? How do I rotate it by 180 degrees by Y axis only?

P.S. I know about `transform.Rotate` but in my case I need to rotate it using the way that I have described here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use [`transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

```
private IEnumerator SmoothlyRotateCamera()
{
    var duration = 0.3f;

    // in angles per second
    var rotationSpeed = 180f / duration;

    float rotated = 0;

    do
    {
        var angle = Mathf.Min(180.0f - rotated, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        var rotation = Vector3.up * angle;

        rotated += angle;

        // depends which Y axis you want to rotate around here
        // pass Space.World to rotate around the global Y axis instead of the local one
        // if left out it rotates around its transform.up vector instead
        transform.Rotate(rotation, Space.World);

        yield return null;
    } while (rotated < 180f);

    isRotating = false;

    // your last yield return is redundant
}
```

I added the `Mathf.Min` to make sure there is no overshooting. As you can see it lands exactly on 180° and **is** smooth in time (you don't need necessarily `Lerp` for that only use `Time.deltaTime`).

In order to show the effect I only changed the duration to `3` instead of `0.3` (which is to fast to notice it).

Rotating around global Y using `transform.Rotate(rotation, Space.World);`

[image]

Rotating around local Y using `transform.Rotate(rotation);`

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does rotate it only by Y axis (duh, transform.rotate works, I've had this before I needed to smoothly rotate it), but, two notes:
1. I needed Lerp
2. Rotation is not precise, with time, it goes wild, before I've allowed only to rotate it strictly by 180 degrees.

Comment: please see the update. 1. You don't need lerp to do smooth stuff. 2. the rotation is limitted to 180°.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Euler Angles.

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y + 180, transform.eulerAngles.);
```

Your code will become:

```
private IEnumerator SmoothlyRotateCamera()
{
    float duration = 0.3f;
    Vector3 from = transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 to = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y +180, transform.eulerAngles.z);

    float elapsed = 0.0f;

    while (elapsed < duration)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles =  Vector3.Slerp(from, to, elapsed / duration);
        elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.eulerAngles = to;

    isRotating = false;

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Just change `transform.rotation = to` to `transform.eulerAngles = to` and yes, everything works fine, thanks! But, is this really the best way to rotate it what way? Still, what about rotating it my way?

Comment: @JackMariani no not really see [transform.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html): `Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values. Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Use Transform.Rotate instead.`

Comment: I agree with derHugo. The issue I see is that this could cause issues after 360 degrees. The easier solution is to make sure it won't. so you keep adding and removing 180. But if derHugo solution works is better.